# matplotlib table columns with different colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to apply different colour maps to different columns of a matplotlib table. Currently I can make one colormap for complete table it doesn't works for me due to extreme values in different columns.

```
normal = plt.Normalize(np.min(table_vals)-50, np.max(table_vals))

tab = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
              colWidths = [0.1]*3, cellLoc='center',
              colLabels=columns, bbox=[-0.6,0,0.5,23], cellColours= plt.cm.RdYlGn(normal(table_vals)))
```

Is there anyway to specify `cellColours`  different for different columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to my own problem. It can be done by providing discrete colormap for the applicable ranges of `tablevalues`. It it should be modified something like this:

```
from matplotlib import colors

cmap1 = colors.ListedColormap(['b', 'g', 'r', 'c','m','y','w', 'b','g'])
bounds=[0,11,18,26,31,61,91,501,701,901]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap1.N)
plt.table(cellText=np.int16(table_vals),
                  rowLabels=rows,
                  cellLoc='center',
                  cellColours= cmap1(norm(table_vals)),
                  loc='bottom')
```

So the `tablevalues` in `range(0,11)` is `blue`, `range(11,18)` is `green` and so on. For overlapping data ranges in each columns someother strategy is needed.